# How to use GetFactList function when embedding CLIPS into C Language

Tags: c, embed, clips

I want to use the GetFactList function to get the fact from the CLIPS.
In the Advanced Guide, it says:

```
void GetFactList(&returnValue,theModule);
DATA_OBJECT returnValue;
void *theModule;
```

and the first argument is A pointer to the caller’s DATA_OBJECT in which the return value will be stored.

I don't know what data type I should use in the C program.
My code is like this:

```
#include "clips.h"
#include <string.h>
main()
{

    char factlist[100];
    InitializeEnvironment();
    Load("constructs.clp");
    Reset();
    GetFactList(&factlist,NULL);
    printf("%s\n",factlist);
    Run(-1L);
}
```

It just outputs unreadable codes.

Thanks for any ideas and suggestions.

Comment: A quick googleing gives: http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/documentation/v630/apg.htm "caller’s DATA_OBJECT in which the return value will be stored. The multifield functions described in section 3.2.4 can be used to retrieve the deffacts names from the list." Look for section 3.2.4

Comment: How about, you just declare a variable `DATA_OBJECT factlist` , as is done in examples in the documentation?

Comment: still output unreadable code with declaring a variable DATA_OBJECT factlist

Comment: So check the relevant parts of the documentation, about how to get things out of a DATA_OBJECT

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835564/get-fact-address-data-type-when-get-fact-list-from-clips/22900356#22900356